# CSS clip uses gpu?

Tags: css, performance, gpu, clip, acceleration

In one HTML5 game I am developing I am using the css feature clip in a css animation. But I realized it's affecting game's performance.

I guess clip is not making use of gpu acceleration (if I am wrong, please let me know). 
There is a way to achieve the same than clip making use of GPU acceleration?

This is my simple animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation 
  {
   0% 
      {
   clip:rect(0px,auto,0px,auto);
  }

  50%
  {
    clip:rect(0px,auto, 69px,auto);
  }

  100% 
      {
   clip:rect(0px,auto,0px,auto);
  }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar result using the translate3d or similar CSS and 3 containers:

html:

```
<input id="run" type="button" value="Run">
<ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li style="position:relative; overflow:hidden;">
        <div id="content" style="background-color:#ff0000; width:100px; height:100px;">
            <p>this is content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<p id="totalFrames">0</p>
```

Javascript:

```
var transform = /(Chrome|Safari)/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? '-webkit-transform' : 'transform',
    run = document.getElementById('run'),
    content = document.getElementById('content'),
    container = document.getElementById('container'),
    ticks = document.getElementById('totalFrames'),
    curPos = 0,
    end = 100;

function tick() {
    var dist = (end - curPos) * .05;
    curPos += dist;

    if (Math.abs(dist) > .01) {
        ticks.innerHTML = requestAnimationFrame(tick, null);
      } else {
        curPos = end;
        end = -curPos;
    }
    content.style[transform] = 'translate3d(0, ' + curPos + 'px, 0)';
    container.style[transform] = 'translate3d(0, ' + -curPos + 'px, 0)';
}
run.addEventListener('click', tick);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/my4Sv/7/

Comment: Replace this `navigator.userAgent` test to something like `'webkitTransform' in document.style`. Also the javascript property isn't `-webkit-transform` but that one I cited before.